Coloured output from native Django test runner
I'm trying to get a colored output (red or green) when running my Django tests with the native Django test runner.
I'm running a poetry virtualenv (python 3.11.6) with Django (5.0.3) and colorama (0.4.6) in a zsh on MacOS but the output remains colourless.
Following the Django documentation, I've set export DJANGO_COLORS="error=yellow/blue,blink;notice=magenta" in my zsh before calling python manage.py test apps.myapp. Yet, the output remains colourless. Same result when adding the --force-color option.
However, spinning up the same virtualenv and executing
from colorama import Fore, Style

print(Fore.RED + 'This is red text' + Style.RESET_ALL)

returns a red text (as expected).
What do I have to do to get a colored output from the native Django test runner without switching to a different one?

For the most basic colors, maybe an option is to use BaseCommand and its styles built from the default PALETTE:
class ColorTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.command = BaseCommand()
        self.style = self.command.style

    def test_colorful_messages(self):
        self.assertTrue(expr=True, msg=self.style.ERROR("1s Test Failed"))
        self.command.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS("First test was successfull"))

        self.assertTrue(expr=False, msg=self.style.ERROR("2nd Test Failed"))

Alternatively, you can override the assertion functions for custom behaviour:
class ColorTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.command = BaseCommand()
        self.style = self.command.style

    def assertTrue(self, expr, msg=None):
        if not expr:
            msg = self.style.ERROR(f"{expr} is not true")
        else:
            msg = self.style.SUCCESS("ok")

        self.command.stdout.write(msg)

    def test_colorful_messages(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
        self.assertTrue(False)


thank you for your suggestion! I'm looking for a more global way to change the runner to format all errors red and the default all-test-succeeded "OK" message green. Adding msg attributes to tests feels tedious…

Well, in this case you should write your own assertion functions instead of using the built-in ones. I will throw another minimal example.

By the time I was writing the code, I thought it was better to override the built-in method instead.

yes, I thought of maybe using a decorator to just transform the default output into something colorful… but does this require to create an own test runner inherited from the default django test runner?

Yes, you would have a class inherit TestCase. I don not see any other alternative in this case. Mainly by the fact that assertions do not return successful values.
